# How do I change selection properties in Jetbrains IDE(s)?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

Several times, while working with Jetbrains' IDE(s), I have faced the following issue:

[image]

The natural selection type is changed to this kind of a selection. When I reload the IDE, it gets back to its normal position. Is it a bug, or a feature of the IDE? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Jetbrains:

Toggling between line and column selection modes

To toggle between the line and the column selection modes, do one of the following:

On the main menu, choose Edit | Column Selection Mode.
On the context menu of the editor, choose Column Selection Mode.
Press Shift+Alt+Insert.

P.S. My guess would be you by accident used the wrong key combination. (I currently use PHPStorm & C-Lion and have not seen this issue)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html) is the documentation for selecting text in Jetbrains' editors.